# Lipschitz constant of Polar parametrization

Tags: plane-curves

If $p(t)=P(e^{it})=r(t)e^{it}$, where $r(t)>0$ is a mapping between $[0,2π]$ i.e. between the unit circle $T$ and a curve, then it seems that $\mathrm{Lip}(p)=\mathrm{Lip}(P)$ but I have't the proof.

Comment: I doubt it. Try this example: $r(t)=1+\epsilon \cos 2t$.. it may or may not work.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev It is not a good example. Maybe some complicated example should be given.

Comment: It is possible to prove that $\text{Lip}(p)\le \text{Lip}(P)$. Let $f:[0,2\pi) \to S^1, f(t)=e^{it}$ (which is clearly invertible, with inverse $g:S^1\to [0,2\pi), g(z)=\arg z\mod 2\pi$.)
For every $t,s \in [0,2\pi)$ with $t\ne s$ we have
$$
\frac{|p(t)-p(s)|}{|t-s|}=\frac{|P(f(t))-P(f(s))|}{|f(t)-f(s)|}\cdot\frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{|t-s|}\le \text{Lip}(P)\text{Lip}(f).
$$
Since $\text{Lip}(f)=1$, it follows that  $\text{Lip}(p) \le \text{Lip}(P)$. As for the other inequality I can't tell whether it's true!

Comment: @Mercy Of course this direction is trivial, because $|e^{it}-e^{is}|\le |t-s|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is true. We may assume that $\mathrm{Lip}(p)=1$, that is, $\dot r^2+r^2\le 1$ where the dot indicates derivative with respect to $t$. Note that $r\le 1$. Our goal is to show that $|r(t)e^{it}-r(0)|\le |e^{it}-1|$ for all $t$. After squaring this simplifies to $$(1)\qquad \qquad 2\cos t\,(1-r(0)r(t))\le 2-r(0)^2-r(t)^2$$ which is trivially true when $\cos t\le 0$. So we only have to deal with $0<t<\pi/2$.

We lose no generality in assuming that $r(t)\le r(0)$. It is convenient to write $r(0)=\cos \alpha$ where $0\le \alpha\le \pi/2$. Integrating differential inequality $\dot r\ge -\sqrt{1-r^2}$, we find that $r(t)\ge \cos(\alpha+t)$. The inequality (1) can be written as 
$$(2)\qquad\qquad r(t)^2-2r(t)\cos\alpha\cos t+\cos^2\alpha-2(1-\cos t)\le 0$$
Since the left hand side is a convex function of $r(t)$, it suffices to verify (2) at the endpoints $r(t)=\cos(\alpha+t)$ and $r(t)=\cos\alpha$.

Plugging $r(t)=\cos(\alpha+t)$ into (2) we get $-(1-\cos t)^2\le 0$. Plugging $r(t)=\cos \alpha$ into (2) we get $-2\sin^2 \alpha  \, (1-\cos t)\le 0$. **QED**

There are somewhat similar lemmas in [Radial extension of a bi-Lipschitz parametrization of a starlike Jordan curve](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.5204) by Kalaj and in [On quasiconformal self-mappings of the unit disk satisfying Poisson's equation](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2011-363-08/S0002-9947-2011-05081-6/) by Kalaj and Pavlović, although in both cases they are about modulus-preserving maps rather than argument-preserving.